# Animate section footer changes in grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I know that you can animate insertions of table view cells and section but sometimes I need to change the footer text to one with a different text or to one that is 'nil'. I need to animate it when a UISwitch is toggled.

Right now I am using [tableView reloadData] but this is ugly and changes the section footer too sudden and without any animations. Apple somehow animates this for example when you turn on Personal Hotspot the section footer is slightly changed and this change is animated.

How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already written the code in `-tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` to adjust in response to the `UISwitch`, you could just send an empty update block to the table view to get it reload with animation.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Does this reload the data source? Because since I am changing the footer the data source will have to be reloaded, right?

Comment: Okay this is somewhat working but when I set the footer text to nil after changing the UISwitch then the footer height resizes correctly but the text stays there (NSLog says it's nil though) and only goes away when I scull the table view.

Comment: Here's a thought. Instead of using `-tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`, you may find it more flexible to create a UIView with a label in it for your section footer and provide it conditionally to the table view with the `-tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`. Since we're managing the footer view directly (instead of plugging in a title and letting the table view handle it), it should animate correctly from having a view with a label to potentially having no footer at all.

Comment: I initially used `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` but then tried `-tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`. I've tried it using both ways not but without any success. I was just told that this doesn't animate and that I should tried fading out the UILabel as a workaround.